# Deserialize from MemoryStream issue

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, memorystream

I need help to figure out how to  deserialize from `MemoryStream`.

```
var xmlStream = new MemoryStream();
e.Extract(xmlStream);

if (xmlStream != null)
{
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(xmlStream);
    var contentItems = new ContentItems();
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ContentItems));
    contentItems = (ContentItems)serializer.Deserialize(tr); // Error is here
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @DanBusha `There is an error in XML document (0, 0).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution

we should add

```
 xmlStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

so the final code looks like

```
var xmlStream = new MemoryStream();
e.Extract(xmlStream);

if (xmlStream != null)
{
    xmlStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var contentItems = new ContentItems();
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ContentItems));
    contentItems = (ContentItems)serializer.Deserialize(xmlStream); // NO ERROR
```